# Error en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: c

Buenas, alguno tiene alguna sugerencia o solución para realizar este programa? Gracias de antemano:

El programa debe recibir de un archivo una serie de números con decimales y crear otro archivo en el que los valores sean la media del valor anterior, el valor propio y el siguiente, en el caso del primer y ultimo valor del nuevo archivo, tenemos que tomar el valor del primer archivo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
FILE *sig, *newsign;
#define N 10

int main()
{
int i = 0, j = 0;
float sin,signal[N];
float nsignal[N];
sig = fopen("signal.txt", "r");
if (sig == NULL) printf("ERROR DE APERTURA\n");
while (!feof(sig))
{
    fscanf(sig, "%f", &sin);
    signal[i] = sin;
    i++;
}

newsign = fopen("signal_new.txt", "w+");
if (newsign == NULL) printf("ERROR DE APERTURA\n");
else for (i = 1; N-2; i++)
{
    nsignal[i] = (signal[i - 1] + signal[i] + signal[i + 1]) / 3;
}
for (i = 0; i = 1; i++) { nsignal[i] = nsignal[i]; }
for (i = N; i = N + 1; i++) { (nsignal[i] = nsignal[i]); }
for (i = 0; i<N + 1; i++) fprintf(newsign, "%f ", nsignal[N]);
fclose(sig);
fclose(newsign);
system("Pause");
}
```

El error recibido es:

> Excepción producida en 0x01051AB4 en JULIOEJERCICIOUNO.exe: 0xC0000005: Infracción de acceso al leer la ubicación 0x0485FFE8. Si hay un controlador para esta excepción, el programa puede continuar de forma segura

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que te aparece al compilar?

Comment: Excepción producida en 0x01051AB4 en JULIOEJERCICIOUNO.exe: 0xC0000005: Infracción de acceso al leer la ubicación 0x0485FFE8.

Si hay un controlador para esta excepción, el programa puede continuar de forma segura.

Comment: Tienes mal puesto el `for( i = 1; N - 2; i++ )`. ¿ No será `i < ( N -2 )` ?

Comment: Hay que saber distinguir entre error en tiempo de compilación (es decir, mientras se genera el programa) de error en tiempo de ejecución (cuando lo ejecutas)... los primeros se producen por problemas sintácticos (variables no declaradas, includes que faltan, un punto y coma que falta, ...) mientras que los segundo se producen porque el algoritmo aplicado es incorrecto... en tu caso el error se produce en tiempo de ejecución así que me he tomado la libertad de corregir el título de la pregunta

Comment: @Trauma gracias a ambos por la ayuda, ahora el problema es que el programa se ejecuta pero no acaba. No sé si me explico, soy nuevo en la plataforma

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que se supone que hace el programa? Si haces debug, ¿dónde falla? ¿qué errores recibes?

Comment: El programa debe recibir de un archivo una serie de numeros con decimales y crear otro archivo en el que los valores sean la media del valor anterior, el valor propio y el siguiente, en el caso del primer y ultimo valor del nuevo archivo, tenemos que tomar el valor del primer archivo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (i = 1; N-2; i++)
    nsignal[i] = (signal[i - 1] + signal[i] + signal[i + 1]) / 3;
```

Ese bucle está mal construído porque el mismo se va a ejecutar hasta que la condición de como resultado 0, es decir cuando `N-2==0`.

Teniendo en cuenta que `N` es una constante con valor `10` queda claro que la condición no se va a cumplir en la vida y en consecuencia `i` acabará teniendo valores incorrectos. Por ejemplo:

```
nsignal[1000] =  (signal[1000 - 1] + signal[1000] + signal[1000 + 1]) / 3;
```

A los sistemas operativos modernos no les suele gustar que un proceso empiece a acceder a posiciones de memoria que no le pertenecen, de tal forma que cuando detectan esta situación suelen matar el proceso para evitar que corrompa la memoria de otros procesos... y esto es precisamente lo que te está pasando a tí (si no actuasen así, al escribir memoria de otros procesos el sistema se quedaría en un estado inestable).

Como te comenta vía comentario @Trauma lo más seguro es que el bucle deba lucir así:

```
for (i = 1; i<N-2; i++)
```

Otra cosa es que la condición sea la que te piden en el programa... viendo el código y sin saber el enunciado del ejercicio es algo que no me queda claro.

Por cierto, los bucles que tienes detras de este también tienen problemas similares con la comparación:

```
for (i = 0; i = 1; i++)
//          ^^^^^ Asignacion

for (i = N; i = N + 1; i++)
//          ^^^^^^^^^ Asignacion
```

Las comparaciones se hacen con `==`:

```
for (i = 0; i == 1; i++)

for (i = N; i == N + 1; i++)
```

Aunque bueno, en el caso del primer bucle... un bucle que empieza con `i=0` y finaliza si `i==1` no es un bucle ya que no hay repetición... su código únicamente se ejecuta una vez con `i=0` y ya está... deberías repasar un poco los conceptos de C y de paso leer con más tranquilidad el enunciado del problema.

Comment: Gracias a vuestros consejos lo he conseguido corregir, un saludo y gracias  .                                                                                    
        nsignal[0] = signal[0];
 nsignal[N-1] = signal[N-1];
 for (i = 1; i <=N -2; i++) nsignal[i] = ((signal[i - 1] + signal[i] + signal[i + 1]) / 3);
 for (i = 0; i<N-1; i++) fprintf(newsign, "%f ", nsignal[i]);
 fclose(sig);
 fclose(newsign);
 system("Pause");
}